# Nilpotent Elements and the Socle

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring with identity such that the quotient ring  $R/S_r$ is abelian, i. e., all idempotents of the quotient are central. Here, $S_r$ means the right socle of the ring $R$. Do the nilpotent elements of $R$ belong to $S_r$?
I have sent before, a post in reverse. 
Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Being commutative ("abelian" is not a term usually used with rings, it's more common with groups) is not the same as all idempotents being central. Easy counterexample: Take a local quotient of a non-commutative polynomial ring, say $R:=\mathbb{Z}\langle X,Y\rangle/(X^3,XY^2,X^2Y,Y^3)$. It has only the idempotents 0 and 1 since it is local, but it is not commutative.

Comment: While the notion of an abelian ring might not be so well-known, it is standard as stated. In particular, it does not coincide with the notion of a commutative ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=K[x]/(x^3)$. Then the socle is $S_r=(x^2)/(x^3)$ and the quotient is abelian because $R$ is abelian.
The element $x mod x^3$ is nilpotent but not in $S_r$.